# Get popup modal inner HTML in Ember Qunit test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I'm doing `integration component` testing with `ember-qunit`. So how to get popup modal **body text** once its open from an action.

**text-bar-test**

```
test('it renders with title', function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);

    this.render(hbs`{{text-bar}}`);
    this.$('.open-app').click();  // opening from text-bar hbs template
    assert.equal(this.$('.body-text').html(), 'its modal-body text', 'Modal body text test once opens');

});
```

Comment: Isn't there any error about runloop in the console? I'm wondering why you don't have to wrap firing jQuery click event in a runloop.

Comment: i tried `Ember.run.schedule`  for **actions**. but still actions are not performed for click. after that a popup is coming that i want to test whether its open or not in component. its **ember-modal-dialog** plugin im using for popup.

Comment: Are you able to setup an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use one of ember's asynchronous test helpers to help manage this. The click event happens, then there are some additional tasks running (like animations and whatnot).

There is a package called ember test helpers and you'll want to use the `wait` or `waitFor` helper: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#waitfor.

The ember guides show this example here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_waiting-on-asynchronous-behavior

If you're using a 3.x version, you can use the `async/await` syntax, which makes things a lot nicer: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_waiting-on-asynchronous-behavior